# shinyapp out of memory despite the memory limit isn't exceeded

Tags: r, memory, shiny, out-of-memory, shinyapps

I created a shiny app that loads .RData reactively. And every time, the new loaded data is loaded over the variable created during the loading of the previous data. Moreover, I don't exceed the memory limit of 1024 MB, as my application is only 550 MB. However, when I try to reactively download one of the big Rdatas, I get `Shiny out of memory` error. I set the Startup timeout to the maximum, so I don't know what the problem is.

How can I fix this problem?

Here is the published website: https://tafn.shinyapps.io/TAFN/

If you choose, for example, the econ_interest_RATE theme on general analysis page, you will see the `app disconnected` problem.

Comment: Are you loading all countries at once despite only one country was selected?

Comment: yes because the datasets are divided based on their theme. However, they are all small, below 200 MB. When you choose a theme, it downloads that respective Rdata, which is loaded as a tibble. Then, when you choose a country, it is filtered.

Comment: Size of R objects might increase after deflating compressed .RData files

Comment: You want to look at a tiny fraction of tabular data at once and do not want can keep everything in RAM. This is a classical use case for a relational database instead of RData files

Comment: So should I keep the Rdatas in smaller files?

Comment: I would use SQLite to save the data. One big file if its <10GB should be enough. Then do queries for each country and load only the result to RAM.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. I have a little experience with SQLite but I think I'll be able to do it.

Comment: Do not forget to create an index on the country column. Queries will be very slow otherwise

Comment: It's not about the size of your application. It's RAM. You may want to learn a bit more what disk space is and what RAM is.  Your app on shinyapps.io is running in a container. To run this container, there is some overhead memory cost, and to start R and Shiny, there is some other memory cost. When your app starts, the app, R objects other datasets take some memory. Then what is left for you in that 1GB RAM is not much. When you are trying to load even small datasets like 200MB into memory, it may still exceed the limit.